# Styled nested divs using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create nested divs in javascript, but it is not woking. Below is the code which I tried.I am applying xternal css them

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <!--<meta charset="UTF-8">-->
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>first2</title>
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsoncss.css">
 </head>
   <script type="text/javascript"             src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>

     /*html=$("<div class='wrapper'>").append(
         $("<div class='LeftSection'>").append(
              $("<div class='MyMainSavings'>")).append(
                               $("<div class='MyMainSavingsTop'>")));*/


      /*$("<div>", {class: "wrapper"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "LeftSection"}).append(
        $("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavings"}).append(
            ("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavingsTop"}),
            ("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavingsBottom"})
        ),
        $("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavings"}).append(
            ("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavingsTop"}),
            ("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavingsBottom"})
        ),
        $("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavings"}).append(
            ("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavingsTop"}),
            ("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavingsBottom"})
        ),
        $("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavings"}).append(
            ("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavingsTop"}),
            ("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavingsBottom"})
        )
    ), 
    $("<div>", {class: "RighSection"}).append(
        $("<span>").text(
            "Some text"
        )
    )
     ).appendTo("body")*/

  var iDiv = document.createElement('div');

    //iDiv.id = 'wrapper';
    iDiv.className = 'wrapper';
     //document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);

      var div2 = document.createElement('div');
          div2.className = 'LeftSection';
     iDiv.appendChild(div2);    

     /*$(document).ready(function () {
         $(".wrapper").addClass("wrapper");
         });*/
      </script>
     <body> 
     </body>
      </html>
```

How to link external css to divs created in javascript?I tried addClass but it dosnt work.
Please consider commented out code also, those are different ideas that i tried.

Comment: More than half of the code you posted is commented out. If that is not relevant why post it? It only adds to the clutter and takes focus away from the problem at hand. Don't be lazy just dumping your code in people's face. Be responsible and post neat and clean code while typing out a question. Read this -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: With all due respect, i posted that code to show what all ideas i have tried.

Comment: That is okay. But, you need to explain your question clearly and clean up the code. Some attempts are using jQuery and some attempts are plain Javascript. Please clean up your code, most of the commented code doesn't apply. Specify clearly what you are wanting to do and your attempted code should reflect that. You get better answers when you post a better question.

Comment: Point taken. Could you help get the code right? What do you think about the code starting right after the script tag?

Comment: This is all what you need -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/5f2rutw2/

Comment: I tried this. But fire bug is showing- TypeError: document.body is null
 

document.body.appendChild(div1);

Comment: That is probably because you must be scripting into the `head` and your script runs before the document is rendered. Move your `script` section to just before the end of `body`.

Comment: Your entire html file should like like this -- https://gist.github.com/abhitalks/b9184044cd92ca1871a8#file-sample-html

Comment: Okay i got it.. Thank you very much

Comment: Would you like to know what I am working on?

Answer (score 0):

After appending element to main tag you can apply other event,

```js
var p = document.getElementById('ptag');

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'wrapper';

var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.id = 'wraper';

div.appendChild(div1);
p.appendChild(div); //<--attac div to main tag

alert($('#ptag')[0].innerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="ptag">

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I could see in your script is your are not appending the IDiv created to any other element in the DOM.

So the finally you need to append it like below

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');

    //iDiv.id = 'wrapper';
    iDiv.className = 'wrapper';
     //document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);

      var div2 = document.createElement('div');
          div2.className = 'LeftSection';
     iDiv.appendChild(div2);    
    document.getElementById('any-parent-element-id').appendChild(iDiv)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way

```
html='<div class="element"><p class="children"></p></div>'; 

$('#wrapper').html(html);
```